# AttributeError on django migrations (production)

Tags: python, django

In production I divided settings to 2 parts prod_settings.py and local_settings.py. For server Gunicorn with Nginx. So after makemigrations command it returns

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

The Traceback is ->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    self.ensure_defaults(alias)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 176, in ensure_defaults
    conn.setdefault('ATOMIC_REQUESTS', False)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
(venv) artashes@multisad:~/multi$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    self.ensure_defaults(alias)
  File "/home/artashes/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 176, in ensure_defaults
    conn.setdefault('ATOMIC_REQUESTS', False)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you kept the settings files name as `prod_settings.py`. I think by changing the file name to normal `settings.py` as Django assumes will fix the error.

If that too doesn't work, try running

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

And then run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: no in settins py I am importing prod settings.py file

Answer (score -1):

Not just your `settings.py` file looks for settings. All of your app along with your project and even `models.py`, `views.py`, `admin.py`, `test.py` and `urls.py` of your project and most importantly Django in its backend looks for the settings of your project in the `settings.py` file. So you will need to change this from each and every place where Django looks for `settings.py` which is technically impossible. So the optimal solution is to change it back to `settings.py`

Comment: This seems like an attempt to reply, rather than a separate answer. You should probably update your first answer to incorporate this information, and delete this second non-answer.